# JQuery is(":focus")

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that for some reason, I cannot perform:

```
$(".exampleClass")[0].is(":focus");
```

It tells me - TypeError: undefined is not a function.
What I am trying to do is grab a few elements with jquery, scan through them, and find which one is focused (so that I can focus the next element in the array programmatically).

```
var fields = $(".textField");
            var selected = false;
            for(var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++){
                var field = fields[j];
                console.log(field);
                if(selected){
                    field.focus();
                }else if(field.is(':focus') && !selected ){
                    selected = true;
                }
            }
```

It all works fine until **field.is(':focus')** Why won't this work?

Comment: use: `$($(".exampleClass")[0]).is(":focus");` or `$(".exampleClass:first").is(":focus");`

Comment: put that in an answer so I can give you my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you index into the jQuery object with the `[ ]` operator, you extract the underlying component of the list of matched elements. That component will be a DOM node, and it won't have a `.is()` method.

If you coded it like

```
$(".exampleClass").eq(0).is(":focus");
```

you'd be working with a jQuery object, and you wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: Ok, I can't seem to find anything to check if that node is focused. What would I use to do this?

Comment: @JustinC. I don't know what you mean; why won't `.is(":focus")` work?

Comment: @JustinC. in the code you posted, just make it `if ($(field).is(":focus"))`. You could use jQuery's `.each()` method to make it cleaner.

Comment: Ah figured it out. you are correct, but I found if I do $($(".exampleClass")[0]).is(":focus"); it seems to work (from a comment posted on my question). Thanks!